# Patch-panel for phone splitter

Tags: networking, phone

I need a phone splitter (RJ11) to split 1 signal into 4 or more outputs. That's no problem, those can be bought in any store. But I was wondering if I can use a RJ45 cat6 patch-panel?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Can you use a patch panel to do what?

Comment: I don't want to use an ugly phone splitter like http://s.s-bol.com/imgbase0/imagebase/large/FC/2/8/9/9/9200000018979982.jpg and was wondering if I could use a patch panel in any way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real reason you can't.  Just wire all the ports to each other, and you'll be fine.  You don't want to swap connectors or anything, just wire everything in parallel.

This is *exactly* what a commercial phone splitter does internally.

Comment: [Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits#Series_circuits)?! You have to wire phone jacks in [parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits#Parallel_circuits).

Comment: So if I link all the keystones in the patch panel together I have actually a splitter?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you have if you link them all together.